# Kafka delete topics when auto.create.topics is enabled

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a 2 node kafka cluster with both `auto.create.topics.enable` and `delete.topic.enable` set to `true`. Our app reads from a common request topic and responds to a response topic provided by the client in the request payload.

`auto.create.topics` is set to `true` as our client has an auto-scale environment wherein a new worker will read from a new response topic. Due to some implementation issues on the client side, there are a lot of topics created which have never been used (end offset is `0`) and we are attempting to clean that up.

The problem is that upon deleting the topic, it is being recreated almost immediately. These topics don't have any consumer (as the worker listening to it is already dead).

I have tried the following

Kafka CLI delete command

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic <topic-name> --delete
```

Create a zookeeper node under

```
/admin/delete_topics/<topic-name>
```

Both don't seem to work. In the logs, I see that a request for delete was received and the corresponding logs/indexes were deleted. But within a few seconds/minutes, the topic is auto-created. Logs for reference -

```
INFO [Partition <topic-name>-0 broker=0] No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition <topic-name>-0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
INFO Replica loaded for partition <topic-name>-0 with initial high watermark 0 (kafka.cluster.Replica)
INFO Replica loaded for partition <topic-name>-0 with initial high watermark 0 (kafka.cluster.Replica)
INFO [Partition <topic-name>-0 broker=0] <topic-name>-0 starts at Leader Epoch 0 from offset 0. Previous Leader Epoch was: -1 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
INFO Deleted log /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-4.7a79dfc720624d228d5ee90c8d4c325e-delete/00000000000000000000.log. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted offset index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-4.7a79dfc720624d228d5ee90c8d4c325e-delete/00000000000000000000.index. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted time index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-4.7a79dfc720624d228d5ee90c8d4c325e-delete/00000000000000000000.timeindex. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted log for partition <topic-name>-4 in /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-4.7a79dfc720624d228d5ee90c8d4c325e-delete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
INFO Deleted log /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-2.d32a905f9ace459cb62a530b2c605347-delete/00000000000000000000.log. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted offset index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-2.d32a905f9ace459cb62a530b2c605347-delete/00000000000000000000.index. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted time index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-2.d32a905f9ace459cb62a530b2c605347-delete/00000000000000000000.timeindex. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted log for partition <topic-name>-2 in /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-2.d32a905f9ace459cb62a530b2c605347-delete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
INFO Deleted log /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-3.0670e8aefae5481682d53afcc09bab6a-delete/00000000000000000000.log. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted offset index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-3.0670e8aefae5481682d53afcc09bab6a-delete/00000000000000000000.index. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted time index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-3.0670e8aefae5481682d53afcc09bab6a-delete/00000000000000000000.timeindex. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted log for partition <topic-name>-3 in /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-3.0670e8aefae5481682d53afcc09bab6a-delete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
INFO Deleted log /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-7.ac76d42a39094955abfb9d37951f4fae-delete/00000000000000000000.log. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted offset index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-7.ac76d42a39094955abfb9d37951f4fae-delete/00000000000000000000.index. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted time index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-7.ac76d42a39094955abfb9d37951f4fae-delete/00000000000000000000.timeindex. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted log for partition <topic-name>-7 in /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-7.ac76d42a39094955abfb9d37951f4fae-delete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
INFO Deleted log /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-1.4872c74d579f4553a881114749e08141-delete/00000000000000000000.log. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted offset index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-1.4872c74d579f4553a881114749e08141-delete/00000000000000000000.index. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted time index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-1.4872c74d579f4553a881114749e08141-delete/00000000000000000000.timeindex. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted log for partition <topic-name>-1 in /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-1.4872c74d579f4553a881114749e08141-delete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
INFO Deleted log /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-0.489b7241226341f0a7ffa3d1b9a70e35-delete/00000000000000000000.log. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted offset index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-0.489b7241226341f0a7ffa3d1b9a70e35-delete/00000000000000000000.index. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted time index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-0.489b7241226341f0a7ffa3d1b9a70e35-delete/00000000000000000000.timeindex. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted log for partition <topic-name>-0 in /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-0.489b7241226341f0a7ffa3d1b9a70e35-delete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
INFO Deleted log /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-5.6d659cd119304e1f9a4077265364d05b-delete/00000000000000000000.log. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted offset index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-5.6d659cd119304e1f9a4077265364d05b-delete/00000000000000000000.index. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted time index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-5.6d659cd119304e1f9a4077265364d05b-delete/00000000000000000000.timeindex. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted log for partition <topic-name>-5 in /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-5.6d659cd119304e1f9a4077265364d05b-delete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
INFO Deleted log /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-6.652d1aec02014a3aa59bd3e14635bd3b-delete/00000000000000000000.log. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted offset index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-6.652d1aec02014a3aa59bd3e14635bd3b-delete/00000000000000000000.index. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted time index /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-6.652d1aec02014a3aa59bd3e14635bd3b-delete/00000000000000000000.timeindex. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
INFO Deleted log for partition <topic-name>-6 in /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-6.652d1aec02014a3aa59bd3e14635bd3b-delete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Removed 0 offsets associated with deleted partitions: <topic-name>-0. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(<topic-name>-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
INFO [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(<topic-name>-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager)
INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(<topic-name>-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
INFO [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(<topic-name>-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager)
INFO Log for partition <topic-name>-0 is renamed to /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0/<topic-name>-0.185c7eda12b749a2999cd39b3f90c738-delete and is scheduled for deletion (kafka.log.LogManager)
INFO Creating topic <topic-name> with configuration {} and initial partition assignment Map(0 -> ArrayBuffer(0, 1)) (kafka.zk.AdminZkClient)
INFO [KafkaApi-0] Auto creation of topic <topic-name> with 1 partitions and replication factor 2 is successful (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(<topic-name>-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
INFO [Log partition=<topic-name>-0, dir=/home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)
INFO [Log partition=<topic-name>-0, dir=/home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0] Completed load of log with 1 segments, log start offset 0 and log end offset 0 in 0 ms (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Created log for partition <topic-name>-0 in /home/ec2-user/data/kafka/0 with properties {compression.type -> producer, message.format.version -> 2.2-IV1, file.delete.delay.ms -> 60000, max.message.bytes -> 1000012, min.compaction.lag.ms -> 0, message.timestamp.type -> CreateTime, message.downconversion.enable -> true, min.insync.replicas -> 1, segment.jitter.ms -> 0, preallocate -> false, min.cleanable.dirty.ratio -> 0.5, index.interval.bytes -> 4096, unclean.leader.election.enable -> false, retention.bytes -> -1, delete.retention.ms -> 86400000, cleanup.policy -> [delete], flush.ms -> 9223372036854775807, segment.ms -> 604800000, segment.bytes -> 1073741824, retention.ms -> 86400000, message.timestamp.difference.max.ms -> 9223372036854775807, segment.index.bytes -> 10485760, flush.messages -> 9223372036854775807}. (kafka.log.LogManager)
INFO [Partition <topic-name>-0 broker=0] No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition <topic-name>-0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
INFO Replica loaded for partition <topic-name>-0 with initial high watermark 0 (kafka.cluster.Replica)
INFO Replica loaded for partition <topic-name>-0 with initial high watermark 0 (kafka.cluster.Replica)
INFO [Partition <topic-name>-0 broker=0] <topic-name>-0 starts at Leader Epoch 0 from offset 0. Previous Leader Epoch was: -1 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
```

Does anyone know the reason behind the topic being re-created when no consumers are listening and no producers are producing to the topic? Could replication be behind it (some race condition perhaps)? We are using **Kafka 2.2**.

Deleting the log directory for that topic directly seems to work, however, this is cumbersome when there are thousands of topics created. We want to have a cleanup script that does this periodically as due to the auto-scale nature of the client environment, there may be frequent orphaned response topics.

**Update**

I tried Giorgos' suggestion by disabling `auto.create.topics.enable` and then deleting the topic. This time the topic did get deleted, but none of my applications through any errors (which leads to me the conclusion that there are no consumers/producers to the said topic).

<strike>Further, when `auto.create.topics.enable` is enabled and the topic is created with a `replication-factor=1`, the topic does not get re-created after deletion. This leads me to believe that perhaps replication is the culprit. Could this be a bug in Kafka?</strike>
Jumped the gun here; turns out something is listening/re-creating these topics from the customer environment.

Comment: Did you check the cleanup.policy on the topics, it needs to be set to delete or the topics will not actually be removed

Comment: The cleanup policy is set to delete with a broker level log ttl of 24 hours.

Comment: It sounds like there is definitely a producer sending to these topics and creating the, have you ran a console consumer on one of the topics to see what kind of data is getting pushed into them?

Comment: There is no data being pushed into these topics at all (which was the implementation problem in the first place). I can understand if the customer is still listening/re-creating the deleted topics but there are topics that I know for sure is not being used (internally created by us but not being used) which are refusing to get deleted.

Comment: By the way, it's not recommended to store Kafka logs under your user directory, but rather on separate drives

Comment: @cricket_007 do you refer to the Kafka logs that hold the actual data that is in a topic? This is interesting as we were having trouble recently with massive data being sent in from a connector that captures changes in a DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you've mentioned that no consumer/producer is consuming/producing from the topic, it sounds that this is the case. Maybe you have any connectors running on Kafka Connect that replicate data from/to Kafka?

If you still can't find what is causing the re-creation of the deleted Kafka topics, I would suggest setting `auto.create.topics.enable` to `false` (temporarily) so that topics cannot be automatically re-created. Then the process that is causing topic re-creation will normally fail and this is going to be reported in your logs.

Comment: This is a good idea to debug further. I don't have control over the client environment  but I can do that for the topics we have created internally.

Comment: You were right. Something is consuming or has a connection within this topic.

Comment: @Mithun Did you manage to find which process is causing this topic re-creation?

Comment: It was from the customer environment. We have requested them to make changes to their implementation to avoid the issue.